# Getting TagLostException when sending SELECT PPSE command

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, emv, contactless-smartcard

I'm getting a tag lost exception when sending SELECT PPSE command using the tag's transceive method.

The intent is passed to `readTag` and the method is getting the tag from the intent but calling the transceive method for the SELECT PPSE command APDU results in a tag lost exception instead of getting the Response APDU message:

```
public void readTag(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        System.out.println("Got the tag");
        Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        NfcA mfc = NfcA.get(tagFromIntent);
        System.out.println(mfc);
        try {
            mfc.connect();
            System.out.println(mfc.getTag());
            System.out.println(mfc.getClass());
            byte[] ATQA = mfc.getAtqa();
            System.out.println(getHexString(ATQA));
            System.out.println(mfc.getMaxTransceiveLength());
            mfc.setTimeout(500000);

            String value = "00A404000e325041592e5359532e444446303100"; //PPSE APDU value
            String hex = value.toString();
            byte[] data = HexToByte(hex);
            byte[] response = mfc.transceive(data); //sending request
            System.out.println(getHexString(response));
            mfc.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tag technology `NfcA` (and also `NfcB`) is for communicating using ISO 14443-3 proprietary command sets. APDUs are typically sent on top of ISO-DEP / T=CL (ISO 14443-4 transmission protocol), so you would want to use `IsoDep` tag technology instead of `NfcA`.

Also you might want to use a slightly lower timeout value. Typically a value in the order of 1 to 10 seconds should be enough (by far) -- unless you trigger some complex operations on the smartcard.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, It worked ,I'm getting the response.Can you guide me in how to form the Select AID from the PPSE response .